# A single word describing exactly 'never' in a collection of frequencies

Tags: single-word-requests

The phrase is:
'(frequency) Notifications'
i.e
'Daily Notifications'
'Weekly Notifications'
'Never Notifications'

The best I've found on the internet is "Unscheduled" but that implies that it can happen, just with some lack of determined frequency. Is it impossible to describe never in the context of frequencies?

Comment: Can you describe a notification that would not be scheduled? That might help people come up with an answer.

Comment: In this context it just means that the notification never sends, but the current view necessitates the use of the above phrase '(word) Notifications'.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a word that's based on the content of the notification, I'm looking for more of a universal word.

Comment: Possibly "Zero Notifications"

Comment: 'how often do you want me to send you notifications [emails]?', daily, weekly, never?

Comment: Daily Notifications, weekly notifications, ***no*** notifications...

Comment: I imagine you're using 'daily notifications' (etc) to mean 'notifications which have never had a gap of 24 hours (etc) or more between them'. But this is a confusing usage.

Comment: Jim, "no notifications" was a good answer too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These might be **withheld, suspended, inactive, deferred**.

All of these describe the condition of not being in operation or effect, as a law, rule, privilege, service, or the like. ([Dictonaary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/suspend))

Here some example sentences:

> Notifications of motion detection have been inactive since the cameras went online.
>
> Notifications of ongoing investigations are suspended to protect the privacy of the investigators.
>
> The email notification feature is inactive, but can be enabled for regular intervals if desired.
>
> Email notifications have been withheld of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Canis Lupus's answer covers the category of things that are not currently active.  Another "never" category is things expressly forbidden.  This might include, for example, internal protocols for working through proper channels, so there might be players who are not supposed to be included directly in notifications.

The most likely term would be **prohibited** ([*to forbid by authority*-M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prohibit)).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider "**null** notifications".

This expresses the idea of "no" or "zero" notifications while maintaining an *adjectival* pattern in describing frequency (daily, weekly, etc.), instead of switching to a quantifying *determiner*.

From [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/null):

> *(MEASURES) having a value of zero*

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/null):

> *of, being, or relating to zero*

**Null** also carries a meaning of *invalidity*, or *lack of effect*. The above-linked Merriam-Webster entry includes:

> *having no legal or binding force :  invalid*

and

> *amounting to nothing*

This reflects a secondary sense of negation which may reach toward the sense you want of "Never notifications", and less towards the sense of potential in "unscheduled".

In the same way "unscheduled" describes the *nature* of the notifications themselves rather than their frequency, **null** would be taken to negate the existence or validity of any notifications under consideration.